# How can I limit my treeview to parent and 1 child? Silverlight 5

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, treeview, silverlight-5.0

I have a treeview that gets generated from a database. However the treeview will change when the application is live as I will be expanding on it using a listbox and drag/drop functionality to build it up. 
However my problem is I only every want it to be parent -> child. I don't want parent -> child -> child. I only want one 'brach' coming off from the parent node. Here is my data template for the treeview:

```
       <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="TreeviewItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <Grid AllowDrop="true" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" AllowDrop="true" >
                <CheckBox x:Name="tick" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Active, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,2,0" Content="{Binding Path=ReasonDescription, Mode=TwoWay}"  AllowDrop="true"
                           x:FieldModifier="Public" />
        </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I have 1 data template which gets both the parent reasons and the child reasons. Is there an extra property that can see if the item is going to be dropped on to a second level to create a third and disable it?
Thanks